# CSS issue with MVC project

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I just created a MVC as Mirosoft suggestion:
[image]

And the result of About page looks like:

[image]

But when I want to extend more header, the layout was broken as below:
[image]

Here is the code in _Layout.cshtml:

```html
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                Expend
            </div>
            <div>
                Expend
            </div>
            <div>
                Expend
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? what is the root cause? 
I'm just studying the MVC for a while.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post your code as image. According to your html code the result is coccrect. what it should look like?

Comment: @Sfili_81, Thank for your comment. I updated html code as your suggestion. If you compare with the first screen, you will see the About header is now behind. I want the partial view with move down to display fully content.

Comment: since we can't see the HTML or CSS which is used to control the area saying "About" it's really not possible to identify the problem. We cannot fix code that we can't see.

Comment: You made changes somewhere, if that was in CSS then include relevant CSS into the question. Also point out exactly what you changed, so we can try to guide you on what to change instead.

Comment: @ADyson and Peter B, like I wrote before, I created MVC project from Microsoft suggestion, you just create like that and add more div to _Layout.cshtml, you can see the change. I have no change anywhere.

Comment: You're assuming people have those tools to hand so that they can create the same thing. Not everyone uses Microsoft tools, or uses the exact same version of them. And anyway, to be on-topic your question must be self-contained, with all the relevant details inside it, so that it's useful to future readers too. Please add enough information to allow us to reproduce your problem just by looking at your question. Thanks.

Comment: We need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Make it easy for people to help you by giving them all the information they need, in one place, from the start. Don't ask them to go away doing other tasks such as creating visual studio projects, in order to understand your problem. People are giving their free time, they want to help you quickly and easily, not spend time messing about trying to work out if they've generated the same code as you! You'll get more help if you make it easy to help you.

Comment: @ADyson, thank for your advices

Comment: No problem. So are you going to update your question then? Or did you solve your issue already?

Answer (score 0):

You added 3 divs without any css class on your header. This is the cause of the "broken" header. Its not broken, its just use the default behavior of a div element.

If you remove this 3 divs your layout will be normal again.

```
 <div>
     Expend
 </div>
```

If will want to add new items to your header menu you need to add hte new items inside the  `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` like below

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
    <li>Put your new link here</li>
</ul>
```

This layout uses bootstrap 3. If you want to customize it the first thing you should learn is the minimum of html and css and then bootstrap 3. To learn bootstrap 3 you can use the w3schools tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp

I would like to reinforce what ADyson said in the comments. We need a minimal, reproducible example. Please when you ask any question remember that what is obvious to you is not obvious to other people.

Hope I'd helped you.